# Cannot invoke MessageDlg

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3 to develop a FireMonkey app.

When calling MessageDlg as below:

```
MessageDlg(‘Hello, world’, mtInformation, [mtOK], 0);
```

I always get an error saying “Undeclared identifier mtInformation” and “Undeclared identifier mtOK”. I searched for the online help and find both should be defined in `System.UITypes`, which has already been added in the `uses` list.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Unit_Scope_Names) have been required since XE2. `MessageDlg('Hello World!', TMsgDlgType.mtInformation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOk], 0);` works.

Comment: @KenWhite this issue is not being caused by Unit Scope Names, this is due to [Scoped Enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)) instead. FireMonkey has Scoped Enums enabled.

Comment: @alancc You have posting a 1/2 dozen questions recently that state you are using XE3, but you tagged all of them as XE2 instead. I have fixed your tags so far, but please use proper tags from now on.

Comment: @KenWhite: `TMsgDlgType` isn't a unit, is it? :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: No, `TMsgDlgType` is not a unit. It's a type. :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. Couldn't quite remember the term, which is why I posted a comment only. Was going to get back to it this morning if no one else did - you did. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to [Scoped Enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)), which FireMonkey has enabled.  So, you must prefix enum values with the enum type name:

```
MessageDlg(‘Hello, world’, TMsgDlgType.mtInformation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mtOK], 0);
```